# Скрипт js частично не работает только на одной странице (во всех браузерах)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Обнаружила такую проблему: скрипт отправки данных формы не отрабатывает полностью на одной из страниц сайта. Данные формы отправляются, но сообщение пользователю ("Ваше сообщение отправлено!") не выводится. Только на одной странице из более 70-ти.

Из-за этого с данной страницы пользователь отправляет форму многократно, т.к. думает, что данные не отправились.

Код скрипта везде одинаков, лежит между закрывающими body и html. WinMerge сообщает при сравнении кода на работающих страницах и на неработающей, что код не имеет отличий.

Может, кто-нибудь с такими чудесами сталкивался?
В чем может быть проблема?

Все страницы - хтмл, которым указано в хтаксесс исполняться как пхп. Вдруг это важно?

```
    <script>
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var data = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        message: document.getElementById('message').value,
        phone: document.getElementById('phone').value
    };
    if (data.name != "" && data.phone != "" && data.lname != "") {
        var query = 'myData=' + JSON.stringify(data);
        doAJAX('api.php', query, function (r) {
            document.getElementById('respond').innerHTML = r;
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById('respond').innerHTML = '';
            }, 3000);
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('respond').innerHTML = 'Заполните поля формы';
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('respond').innerHTML = '';
        }, 3000);
    }
});

function doAJAX(url, data, callback){
    try { var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    catch (e1){
        try { xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
        catch (e2){ 
            try { xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } 
            catch (e3){ xhr = false; }}}
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4){
            if (this.status == 200){
                callback(this.responseText);
            }
        } 
    }
    xhr.send(data);
}
</script>
```

P.S. Прилагаю скрин сообщения консоли. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В представленном коде нет сообщения "Ваше сообщение отправлено"

Comment: Да, я и сама это вижу :) Однако, на других страницах сайта такое сообщение появляется. Я откровенно чайник в программировании. Мой потолок - верстка.

Comment: Откройте консоль разработчика и смотрите что там происходит.

Comment: "Ваше сообщение отправлено" должен выводить скрипт-обработчик, видимо. api.php он называется. Лежит на сервере. Для всех других страниц нормально отрабатывает. В консоли никаких проблем не вижу.                   Вот что пишет: POSThttps://baseflat.ru/api.php
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 141ms] ну, и много всего, никаких ошибок, вроде бы

Comment: Добавила скрин того, что вижу в консоли. Может, не туда смотрю?

Comment: `callback(this.responseText);` - вызывается?